# com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2ClientBuilder: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, noclassdeffounderror

**So I am wondering what could be the cause of this error message :**

com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2ClientBuilder: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2ClientBuilder**
at com.stopinstance.InstanceControlLambda.(InstanceControlLambda.java:14)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2ClientBuilder. Current classpath: file:/var/task/

com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2ClientBuilder: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

**I have checked my dependencies that they are the using the same version, but it seems to me that there is still an issue with the ec2ClientBuilder...**

Here is my lambda code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOiV8.jpg)

Here is my pom.xml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7fKI.png)

Here is my template.yaml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Ojd.png)

**I would appreciate any help ! **

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Amazon EC2 and Java, then use the recommended version which is ***AWS SDK for Java V2***, not V1 version. V1 does not reflect best practice.

To use EC2 and [Java EC2 API](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/ec2), you use this code to build the client.

```
 Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
  Ec2Client ec2 = Ec2Client.builder()
      .region(region)
      .build();
```

The POM file with all the required dependencies can be found in the above link.

If you are not familiar with AWS SDK for Java V2, refer to the [DEV Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html).

You can find many EC2 examples here:

[Amazon EC2 examples using SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/java_2_ec2_code_examples.html)